# Citation color: hyperef citecolor modification has no effect

Tags: hyperref, color, citing

I am writing to you as I did not find a solution or answer to this question, either on this site or others.
Specifically, I am having troubles with the color of my citations, which is stuck to blue no matter what changes I make (e.g. here; although the citecolor=red for instance, all of my citations are in blue). I wonder if that has something to do with the packages imported so here is the test code.

```
\documentclass[9pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\journal{Journal of Resources, Conservation \& Recycling}  % Submitted to journal...

% Symbols and language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosym}

% Geometry
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\usepackage{lscape}

% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xparse}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Iintv}[1]{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}{\iintvargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\iintvargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\iintvargsaux#1} %
\NewDocumentCommand{\iintvargsaux}{mm} {#1\mkern1.5mu..\mkern1.5mu#2}

% Figure and tables package
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize},labelfont={bf,footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

% Enumerate package
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Color packages
\usepackage{xcolor} 

% Hyper-references packages
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false, bookmarksnumbered=true,colorlinks=true,setpagesize=false, bookmarkstype=toc, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=black, filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\let\OLDthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{
  \OLDthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
}

% Bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}

\citep{author} shall be red. 

\bibliography{biblio.bib} 

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class is redefining the colors at `\begin{document}`. Use \hypersetup to overwrite this again:

```
\documentclass[9pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{citecolor=red}} %force red

\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}

\citep{doody} shall be red.

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you Ulrike for your help, it works all fine ! :)

Comment: How can you also color the parenthesis? Or in ieee the brackets